# Download files from SFTP with SSH.NET library

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp

```
string host = @"ftphost";
string username = "user";
string password = "********";
string localFileName  = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"localfilename");
string remoteDirectory = "/export/";
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
    sftp.Connect();
    var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (!file.Name.StartsWith("."))
        {
            string remoteFileName = file.Name;
            if (file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today)

            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);

            File.OpenWrite(localFileName);

            string sDir = @"localpath";

            Stream file1 = File.OpenRead(remoteDirectory + file.Name);
            sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory, file1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using SSH.NET (`Renci.SshNet`) library to work with an SFTP server. What I need to do is grab files from a specific folder on the SFTP server based on today's date. Then copy those files from the SFTP server to a local drive a server of mine.

Above is the code I have but it is not working. Sometimes it says file does not exist but sometimes the files I will be downloading will not be on my local servers but I need to download whatever files were uploaded to the remote folder for that day.

Can someone take a look and see what is wrong? I believe it has something to do with the stream portion. I have worked with FTP much besides uploading files which I took some previous code I had and thought I could reverse the process but that isn't working. The code I used is based off of this [example](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Draft%20for%20Documentation%20page).

Answer (score 62):

A simple working code to download a file with SSH.NET library is:

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\target\local\path\file.zip"))
{
    sftp.DownloadFile("/source/remote/path/file.zip", fileStream);
}
```

See also [Downloading a directory using SSH.NET SFTP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52392766/850848).

---

*To explain, why your code does not work:*

*The second parameter of `SftpClient.DownloadFile` is a stream to write a downloaded contents to.*

*You are passing in a read stream instead of a write stream. And moreover the path you are opening read stream with is a remote path, what cannot work with `File` class operating on local files only.*

*Just discard the `File.OpenRead` line and use a result of previous `File.OpenWrite` call instead (that you are not using at all now):*

```
Stream file1 = File.OpenWrite(localFileName);

sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, file1);
```

*Or even better, use `File.Create` to discard any previous contents that the local file may have.*

*I'm not sure if your `localFileName` is supposed to hold full path, or just file name. So you may need to add a path too, if necessary (combine `localFileName` with `sDir`?)*

Answer (score 31):

While the example works, its not the correct way to handle the streams...

You need to ensure the closing of the files/streams with the **using** clause..
Also, add try/catch to handle IO errors...

```
       public void DownloadAll()
    {
        string host = @"sftp.domain.com";
        string username = "myusername";
        string password = "mypassword";
        
        string remoteDirectory = "/RemotePath/";
        string localDirectory = @"C:\LocalDriveFolder\Downloaded\";

        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
        {
            sftp.Connect();
            var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);
            
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string remoteFileName = file.Name;
                if ((!file.Name.StartsWith(".")) && ((file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today))

                    using (Stream file1 = File.Create(localDirectory + remoteFileName))
                    { 
                        sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory + remoteFileName, file1);
                    }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

My version of @Merak Marey's Code. I am checking if files exist already and different download directories for .txt and other files

```
        static void DownloadAll()
    {
        string host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        string username = "@@@";
        string password = "123";string remoteDirectory = "/IN/";
        string finalDir = "";
        string localDirectory = @"C:\filesDN\";
        string localDirectoryZip = @"C:\filesDN\ZIP\";
        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " + host + " as " + username);
            sftp.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {

                string remoteFileName = file.Name;

                if ((!file.Name.StartsWith(".")) && ((file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today)))
                { 

                    if (!file.Name.Contains(".TXT"))
                    {
                        finalDir = localDirectoryZip;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        finalDir = localDirectory;
                    }


                    if (File.Exists(finalDir  + file.Name))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File " + file.Name + " Exists");
                    }else{
                        Console.WriteLine("Downloading file: " + file.Name);
                          using (Stream file1 = File.OpenWrite(finalDir + remoteFileName))
                    {
                        sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory + remoteFileName, file1);
                    }
                    }
                }
            }



            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: If you want to add something based on extention use FileInfo fi, you can simply do: `string ext = fi.Extension;` And a switch. Because  `LOVE-LETTER-FOR-YOU.TXT.vbs` will be a false positive. or `Path.GetExtension(myFilePath);`

Comment: beware, you are checking if filename contains ".TXT" and depending on the Server OS you may get ".txt" (lowercase)..it will be a good idea to lowercase remoteFilename variable and use it for the conditions too instead of file.Name...

Comment: Better:  if (!file.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".txt"))

Answer (score 2):

Massimiliano's solution has one problem which will lead to files not being completely downloaded.  The FileStream must be closed.  This is especially a problem for encrypted files.  They won't completely decrypt intermittently without closing the stream.

```
var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteVendorDirectory).Where(f => !f.IsDirectory);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var filename = $"{LocalDirectory}/{file.Name}";
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading  " + file.FullName);
        using (var localFile = File.OpenWrite(filename))
            sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, localFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem on my end.

```
var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteVendorDirectory).Where(f => !f.IsDirectory);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var filename = $"{LocalDirectory}/{file.Name}";
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading  " + file.FullName);
        using (var localFile = File.OpenWrite(filename))
              sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, localFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without you providing any specific error message, it's hard to give specific suggestions.

However, I was using the same example and was getting a permissions exception on File.OpenWrite - using the localFileName variable, because using Path.GetFile was pointing to a location that obviously would not have permissions for opening a file > C:\ProgramFiles\IIS(Express)\filename.doc

I found that using System.IO.Path.GetFileName is not correct, use System.IO.Path.GetFullPath instead, point to your file starting with "C:\..."

Also open your solution in FileExplorer and grant permissions to asp.net for the file or any folders holding the file.  I was able to download my file at that point.

Answer (score -1):

```
string host = @"ftphost";
string username = "user";
string password = "********";
string localFileName  = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"localfilename");
string remoteDirectory = "/export/";
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
    sftp.Connect();
    var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);
    files = files.Select(x => x.IsRegularFile);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
            string remoteFileName = file.Name;
            if (file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today)

            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);

            File.OpenWrite(localFileName);

            string sDir = @"localpath";

            Stream file1 = File.Create(remoteDirectory + file.Name);
            sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory, file1);
        }
    }
}
```